# PyQt5 Installation on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, pyqt5

### What I Know

What I did was:

```
pip install pyqt5
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

The installation went successfully and there was no problem.

### Designer

I expected that executing the commands in the above section, the PyQt5 Designer should be installed. But when I navigated to where PyQt5 was installed, I couldn’t find any `designer.exe` file.
Am I supposed to run any command?

I am using Python 3.9 on Windows.

Comment: Use  `python -m pip install pyqt5` and then execute: `python -c "import PyQt5; print(PyQt5.__file__)"`

Comment: @eyllanesc  I edited the question, so that it becomes more clear what I exactly want to do

Comment: PyQt5 and PyQt5-tools are 2 unrelated libraries (maybe the name causes confusion). So don't look for the executable in the PyQt5 folder, PyQt5-tools must have another folder with that name.

Comment: @eyllanesc I searched in all the directories that have ‘pyqt’ or ‘pyqt5’ in their names but couldn’t find any file called ```designer.exe```. Is the designer available in a completely different package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Found the Solution

It’s simple; you have to just run this command in your `cmd`/`powershell`/`terminal`:

```
pip install pyqtdesigner
```